# pocketsphinx.js - prevent accepting wrong words

Tags: speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

i am trying to use pocketsphinx.js for speechrecognition in my Webapp.
My Problem is, that the software tries to recognize everything it hears
as a right word.

And i am wondering because all Demos i found behaves the same.

So for example take this demonstration: https://touchless-timer.appspot.com/timer/en.html#
It's made for setting an alarm in english.

But when i'm saying something in german, it always prints me out that it has understood
something correct like "setting the alarm to...."

So how should i use it, when it recognizes always correct input even if i'm speaking
a different language?

Hope my Question is understandable.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can introduce hotword and use keyword spotting to listen continuously and reject out-of-grammar words.

Answer (score 0):

Pocketsphinx accuracy is good when you about to recognize predefined commands.

You have a list, but now all the wrong words recognized as your limited dict and looks like it's a way how it works.

What you can try to do:

- filter out output by a confidence that is returned by a decoder.
- use a keyword so user have to say a keyword and you will expect the input after that.
- As an alternative you can add few more common words as fallback to your dictionary so  Pocketsphinx will match them instead your "correct" list, **maybe** this will increase accuracy. (but it can be even worth)

"So how should i use it?"

You should understand that it's works good only with a predefined limited dictionary, if you are waiting for a keyword you can suggest that user **knows how to use your system**. So you can expect that after "hello, Pocketsphinx" will say something from your predefined list.